# Any Plug-In or Substitution for PhoneGap multiple images selection?

Tags: cordova

I had already search for this function for a **long time**, but most of reply finally point to [CB1215](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1215) and this core API had not yet support.

Any one know any Plug-In or Substitution for  PhoneGap  multiple images selection?

Thx for any reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a matter of cordova's core api but it's Android webview that does not support multiple files selection. Try to upload multiple files on any site via androids webbrowser -> you can't. Phonegap plugins are, in the end, using core android features, so unless you can't do it in webview, you won't do it with any plugins unfortunately (it's working on iOS though)

Comment: I would like to correct you on "...Try to upload multiple files on any site via androids webbrowser -> you can't...". Infact, we can select multiple files on modern android browsers. I tried to open this link from my android browser and its working: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_multiple